# How to config ESLint for React on Atom Editor

Tags: atom-editor, reactjs, eslint

In Atom Editor I installed the following plugins

1. linter
2. linter-eslint

It seems they don't recognize the JSX syntaxis.

I have it working on the command line but had to use other plugins like `esprima-fb` and `eslint-plugin-react`. Looks like there are no such plugins for Atom Editor and would like to know if anyone of you knows a way to hack around this.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

To get Eslint working nicely with React.js:

1. Install linter & linter-eslint plugins
2. Run `npm install eslint-plugin-react`
3. Add `"plugins": ["react"]` to your .eslintrc config file
4. Add `"ecmaFeatures": {"jsx": true}` to your .eslintrc config file

Here is an example of a `.eslintrc` config file:

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "node": true
    },

    "globals": {
        "React": true
    },

    "ecmaFeatures": {
        "jsx": true
    },

    "plugins": [
        "react"
    ]
}
```

I am using Eslint v1.1.0 at the moment.

*Side note*:
I had to install both eslint and eslint-plugin-react as project dependencies (e.g., `npm install eslint eslint-plugin-react --save-dev`). Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Have you ever encountered with "ESLint Parsing error: Unexpected token" ?

Comment: In addition to Jon's list I had to install [Atom React Plugin](http://orktes.github.io/atom-react/)

Comment: I'm getting import error on `import React, {Component} from 'react';` after configuring like you said.

Comment: That means eslint is working. You'll need to allow modules in ecmaFeatures. Add `"modules": true` in the `ecmaFeatures` section.

Comment: @JonSaw Thanks for the answer. Do you know if it is possible to run this when `eslint` and `eslint-plugin-react` are not a direct dependency?

Comment: Restarting atom helped me.

Answer (score 36):

Updated answer for 2016: just install the [`react`](https://orktes.github.io/atom-react/) package in Atom and add a `.eslintrc` file in your project root (or in your home dir) containing the following:

```
{
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    }
  },
  "env": {
    "es6": true
  }
}
```

And re-open any files containing JSX and it should work.

Comment: Can you add more details here?

Comment: The package name is just 'react' now https://orktes.github.io/atom-react/

Answer (score 7):

You need to edit a project local [`.eslintrc`](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuration-file-formats) file that will get picked up by ESLint. If you want integration with Atom, you can install the plugins [linter](https://atom.io/packages/linter) and [linter-eslint](https://atom.io/packages/linter-eslint).

To quickly setup ESLint for React best practices, current best option is installing the npm package [`eslint-plugin-react`](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react) and extending their `recommended` configuration instead of toggling many rules manually:

```
{
  "extends": [ "eslint:recommended", "plugin:react/recommended" ],
  "plugins": [ "react" ]
}
```

This will enable `eslint-plugin-react` and recommended rules from ESLint & React presets. There is more valuable information in the latest ESLint [user-guide](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring) itself.

Here is an example of parser options optimized for ES6 and webpack:

```
{
  "parserOptions": {
    "sourceType": "module",
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "impliedStrict": true,
      "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true,
      "jsx": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe JSX is already enabled in their recommended config.

Answer (score 0):

I use Atom and it works just fine. You just need an `.eslintrc` in your project root which tells ESLint that you're using `eslint-plugin-react`.

Answer (score 0):

1. For Mac user: Go to Atom --> preferences --> Install --> search package linter-eslint  --> click install
2. For Ubuntu user: Go to Edit --> preferences --> Install --> search package linter-eslint  --> click install
3. go to command line ---> npm install --save-dev eslint-config-rallycoding
4. Come to atom make new file .eslintrc and extend the rallycoding.