# Intellij plugin: AirBnB ESLint w/ React

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, reactjs, eslint

Using Intellij Idea 15.0.2 on Ubuntu 15.10 and trying to configure ESLint to work.

Followed the instructions on Jetbrains' site, but no dice.

[Here's a screencap of my](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wMwn.png) settings at languages&frameworks > javascript > code quality tools > ESLint. [And here's a screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrfeU.png) of my nodejs/npm settings within IntelliJ.

And my `.eslintrc` file, in the root project directory:

```
{
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "rules": {
    "comma-dangle": 0
  }
}
```

Here's a snip from `/index.js` that produces no errors or warnings in IntelliJ:

```
var superman = {
    default: { clark: "kent" },
    private: true
};
```

Here's the output when I run `eslint index.js` from the terminal:

```
   4:1   error    Unexpected var, use let or const instead                      no-var
   5:5   error    Expected indentation of 2 space characters but found 4        indent
   5:23  error    Strings must use singlequote                                  quotes
   6:5   error    Expected indentation of 2 space characters but found 4        indent
```

Note: I believe ESLint is running, since before I changed my `.eslintrc` to the AirBNB version, I was using an `.eslintrc` from Github that threw a number of ESLint errors in IntelliJ (that is, errors in the `.eslintrc` file itself, not my code).

Once I fixed those errors, though, the plugin quieted down and didn't yell at me when I tested it by producing mistakes.

Comment: couldn't post more than 2 links in OP b/c of rep limitations, so:

  [the `.eslintrc` from github](https://gist.github.com/nkbt/9efd4facb391edbf8048) that produced errors


the [walkthrough on jetbrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/using-javascript-code-quality-tools.html) I followed to config ESLint IntelliJ plugin.

Comment: maybe this will help https://www.themarketingtechnologist.co/how-to-get-airbnbs-javascript-code-style-working-in-webstorm/

Comment: wow. how'd i miss that--thanks, i'd basically given up on that.

if you want to post that as an answer, i'll mark as accepted

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### JetBrains (Idea, Webstorm) settings

`File > Settings > Plugins > Browse repositories... > Search: eslint > Install > Restart WebStorm`

`File > Settings > Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Code Quality Tools > ESLint`

[image]

After that it should work like this:

[image]

### ESLint config

ESLint doesn't come with a config. You have to create your own or use a preset:

```
npm install --save-dev eslint-config-airbnb eslint
```

Then in your .eslintrc

```
{
  "extends": "airbnb"
}
```

You can also selectively disable/modify some rules from preset (0 - disable rule, 1 - warning, 2 - error):

```
{
  'extends': 'airbnb',
  'rules': {
    'indent': [2, 'tab', { 'SwitchCase': 1, 'VariableDeclarator': 1 }],
    'react/prop-types': 0,
    'react/jsx-indent-props': [2, 'tab'],
  }
}
```

Read: [Turning off eslint rule for a specific line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27732209/turning-off-eslint-rule-for-a-specific-line).

If you don't want to use airbnb config (most popular javascript style guide) you can create your own. Here is the instruction for react: [How to config ESLint for React on Atom Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30294870/how-to-config-eslint-for-react-on-atom-editor).

To create your own preset you have to create npm package named eslint-config-myname and then use `'extends': 'myname',` http://eslint.org/docs/developer-guide/shareable-configs

You can use command line to check if eslint works:

```
./node_modules/.bin/eslint .
```

You may though exclude some files from eslinting (node_modules are excluded by default) in .eslintignore:

```
bundle.js
```

There is also a `--fix` switch for eslint.

### .editorconfig

Good companion for ESLint is editorconfig. Here is an example which works in JetBrains products:

```
root = true

# Unix-style newlines with a newline ending every file
[*]
end_of_line = lf
insert_final_newline = true


# Matches multiple files with brace expansion notation
# Set default charset
[*.{js,jsx,html,sass}]
charset = utf-8
indent_style = tab
indent_size = 4
trim_trailing_whitespace = true

# don't use {} for single extension. This won't work: [*.{css}]
[*.css]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2
```

I also have a github repository which already has these files set https://github.com/rofrol/react-starter-kit/

Based on this https://www.themarketingtechnologist.co/how-to-get-airbnbs-javascript-code-style-working-in-webstorm/

More here https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/using-javascript-code-quality-tools.html

Comment: you also have to use `babel-parer`, or the *airbnb* extends would not work correctly

Comment: @BruceLee Do you talk about this https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/issues/589#issuecomment-618436179 ?