# react-native : Parsing error: Unexpected token <

Tags: react-native

i am new to the react-native and i am using Atom GUI 1.12.6 on windows 7 and Exponent for deploying app in android phone 
this was my code

```
'use strict';

import Exponent from 'exponent';
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import { AppRegistry, Text } from 'react-native';

class App extends Component{
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = {
        };
    }

    render(){}
      return (
          <Text>Hello world again!</Text>
      );
   }
}
Exponent.registerRootComponent(App);
```

.eslintrc file contains rules :

```
{
    "extends": "airbnb/base",
    "plugins": [
        "react"
    ],
    "env": {
        "node": true,
        "jasmine": true,
    },
    "rules": {
        "indent": [1, 4],
        "no-console": 0,
        "no-unused-vars": [1, {"vars": "local", "args": "none"}],
        "react/forbid-prop-types": 1,
        "react/jsx-boolean-value": 1,
        "react/jsx-closing-bracket-location": 1,
        "react/jsx-curly-spacing": 1,
        "react/jsx-indent-props": 1,
        "react/jsx-key": 1,
        "react/jsx-max-props-per-line": 1,
        "react/jsx-no-duplicate-props": 1,
        "react/jsx-no-undef": 1,
        "react/jsx-quotes": 1,
        "react/jsx-sort-prop-types": 1,
        "react/jsx-sort-props": 1,
        "react/jsx-uses-react": 1,
        "react/jsx-uses-vars": 1,
        "react/no-danger": 1,
        "react/no-did-mount-set-state": 1,
        "react/no-did-update-set-state": 1,
        "react/no-direct-mutation-state": 1,
        "react/no-multi-comp": 1,
        "react/no-set-state": 1,
        "react/no-unknown-property": 1,
        "react/prefer-es6-class": 1,
        "react/prop-types": 1,
        "react/react-in-jsx-scope": 1,
        "react/require-extension": 1,
        "react/self-closing-comp": 1,
        "react/sort-comp": 1,
        "react/wrap-multilines": 1,
        "id-length": 0,
    },
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
}
```

Getting error : 
 in Atom Editor on Text control it is showing "Parsing error: Unexpected token <" if you ignore that and start deploy in the android phone using exponent  in phone it showing red screen with error :"Unexpected token  '<'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your have a typo in the render method..

```
render(){}
```

Change to:

```
render() {
    return (
        <Text>Hello world again!</Text>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks now i am able to deploy the app in the phone, but in Atom Editor on Text control it is showing "Parsing error: Unexpected token <"  how to solve this ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Atom, but you might be using wrong Atom syntax highlight that doesn't recognize react..or eslint is not configured well..
See [react Atom plugin](https://orktes.github.io/atom-react/) and [configure eslint for react in Atom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30294870/how-to-config-eslint-for-react-on-atom-editor)